# Jira oAuth oauth_signature param missing in PHP

Tags: php, rest, oauth, jira, guzzle

I am using [this library](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/master/php/) for Jira oAuth and configured everything as they suggested. But when I am clicking on authentication URL, it generates a below error

```
 oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_signature&oauth_problem=parameter_absent
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: (Just a quick reminder Rohit, there's no need to add "Hi", "Thanks in advance" etc - this is not a chatroom. Use a spell-checker if you can, they are very easy to install inside browsers these days. See the edits to your prior posts. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your private key file is accessible from that page.

I had the same issue and resolved it by executing this:

```
chmod 777 /path/to/private/key.pem
```

Comment: thanks yes it was the wrong certificate issue.
Could you please let me know was you able to make the attachment api works with this library. i tried a lot but no susces. If you can help in this that will be huge help. Thanks

Comment: I am using it like 
$attachment = $oauth->getClient('oauth_toekn','oauth_secret')->post('endpoint_xxxxx', $headers_array, array ('file' => 'test.txt'));

But Jira returning Media type not supported.

Comment: @RohitGoel your comments lacks enough information to answer your question, like what's the used API and which version you're on? where is the "text.txt" file located ? and what kind of response are you getting currently ?
This is a whole new question that you should be added alone and not discussed in comments.
As for my answer to the above question, if it solved your problem, mark it as the accepted answer.